# Scalacheck prop type mismatch

Tags: scala, types, type-mismatch, scalacheck

I've come across this error a few times. It's pretty self explanatory, the mismatch is coming on my ans var that is an Int, as I believe it should be, however it's wanting type prop. I have a feeling it's syntax related, the way I'm constructing this, but let me know what you think:

[image]

Comment: Please post your source code directly and not such an image.

Comment: In case your problem is solved, you have the opportunity to help me clinch my first accept ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of the implication operator is:

```
def ==>(p: ⇒ Prop): Prop
```

Assuming implicit conversions are in scope, it should be possible to construct a `Prop` from a `Boolean`. Therefore, you only need brackets around `(ans == n*m)`. Otherwise the argument to `==>` will just be `ans`, i.e. an `Int`, which cannot be converted to `Prop`.

The required implicit conversion is:

```
 implicit def propBoolean(b: Boolean): Prop
```

and is in object `Prop`, so ensure to `import org.scalacheck.Prop.propBoolean`.